# Adding horizontal line to chart (plotly)

Tags: plotly

I am reading out a CSV file and plot the content with plotly.
Now I want to add a horizontal line at 40 on the secondary y axis over the complete x axis.
But I cannot figure out how to add this just on the secondary y axis.

Can someone help please?

The CSV file contains distance and speed of sound measurements. I am adding this to a graph like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(folder_path+filename)
fig = px.line(df19, x='Odo', y='E1')
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(
go.Scatter(x=df['Distance'], y=df['SoundVelocity'], mode='lines', 
name='Reference Sensor A', line=dict(color="#70E305")),
secondary_y=False,)
fig.add_shape(type='line',
            x0=0,
            y0=40,
            x1=df19['Distance].max(),
            y1=40,
            line=dict(color='Red',),
            xref='x',
            yref='y',
            secondary_y=True,
)
```

Afterwards, I am just defining graph titels, axis title and where to save a HTML file with the plot and the name of it.
I updated my code recently with the fig.add_shape but it is still plotted on the primary axis

Greets,
Jan

Comment: Presenting reproducible data and code is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: Added the required information